# Safe multithreading Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

I want to download data using 3 API codes, and I would like to multi-thread the APIs (one thread per API). Would something like this work and be safe from data races?

```
# DataKeys: a DataFrame object with keys to search for
len_data=size(DataKeys)[1]

array_split=[1,floor(Int, len_data/3),floor(Int,2*len_data/3), floor(Int,len_data)]

api_keys=[api1, api2, api3]
data_slices=[DataFrame(), DataFrame(), DataFrame()]

Threads.@threads for k in 1:3
     key=api_keys[k]
     for i in array[k]:array[k+1]
         loc=DataKeys[i,:index]
         r=HTTP.get(url(loc),headers)
         json_r=JSON3.read(String(r.body))
         temp=DataFrame(json_r[:data])
         global data_slices[k]=vcat(data_slices[k], temp)
      end
end
```

On the one hand, I feel I should be safe since every thread works on a different element of `data_slices`, but OTOH they're all part of the same vector.

Updated with more details on the function within the threaded `for`.

Things do seem to work fine on this simple example:

```
using DataFrames

len=120

array_split=[1,floor(Int, len/3),floor(Int,2*len/3), floor(Int,len)]
data_slices=[DataFrame(), DataFrame(), DataFrame()]

Threads.@threads for k in 1:3
    for loc in array_split[k]:array_split[k+1]
        temp=DataFrame(k=k,squared=loc^2,half=loc/2, thrd=Threads.threadid())
        global data_slices[k]=vcat(data_slices[k],temp)
    end
end

data_fin=vcat(data_slices...)
```

although the order of the threads is `[1,3,2]` which is a bit odd. Also odd is that for this simple example, I ran a threaded and a non-threaded loop and the non-threaded one is faster (`len=120000`):

```
Threaded: 14.789920 seconds (20.25 M allocations: 72.492 GiB, 28.02% gc time, 3.78% compilation time)
Non-threaded  9.614164 seconds (19.14 M allocations: 72.434 GiB, 11.00% gc time)
```

Comment: It is impossible to say if this code is OK or not as it depends how `read_data` function works and how you compute `condition` (which is not shown in the code).

Comment: Those parts are independent. I have a large DataFrame with indices (```blocks_init```) and the API just retrieves a value for the particular index. So the first thread in the main for searches the first 1/3rd of indices, retrieves values and puts them in the first element of ```data_slices```; the second thread looks at the second 1/3rd etc.

Comment: The code is thread safe. However, it is not correct even in a single threaded mode (you use wrong indexing for `loc` range) and is not optimal from performance perspective (these two things are unrelated to your question so I do not go deeper here). Sequence of threads is not deterministic so this is expected. The performance comparison is not reliable as your first code spent more time in GC which could be by chance. Also it is not clear from your example what is the performance bottleneck in your code. If it is HTTP request then maybe just using `@async` with green threads would be faster.

Comment: In general - if you want to discuss the design of your code in general I recommend you ask the question on Julia Discourse rather than SO (as on SO it is easier to answer Q&A type of closed questions).